# Unable to access NSMutableArray Objects even after declaring properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I am stuck with a very weird problem, atleast for me, unable to figure out what's the solution .The Problem is I have got two nsMutableArrays declared in interface

```
 NSMutableArray *lastItemForFormula;  
 NSMutableArray *lastItemForExpression;  

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *lastItemForFormula;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *lastItemForExpression;
```

and then synthesized them in the implementation:

```
@synthesize lastItemForFormula;
@synthesize lastItemForExpression;
```

Trying to use it my my function like this:

```
-(void)elementClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btnClicked=(UIButton*)sender;  
    NSString* formula=[label text];  
    NSString *stringToBeConcatenated=[elements objectAtIndex:btnClicked.tag];  
    formula=[formula stringByAppendingString:stringToBeConcatenated];  
    [lastItemForFormula addObject:[formula copy]]; //First 
    [label setText:formula];  
    stringToBeConcatenated=[elements objectAtIndex:btnClicked.tag+1];  
    if ([labelExpression.text length]==0) {  
        [lastItemForExpression addObject:[stringToBeConcatenated copy]];  //Second
        [labelExpression setText:[lastItemForFormula objectAtIndex:[lastItemForFormula count]]];  
    }  
    else {  
        [lastItemForExpression addObject:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@+%@",[labelExpression text], stringToBeConcatenated] copy]]; //Third 
        [labelExpression setText:[lastItemForFormula objectAtIndex:[lastItemForFormula count]]];  
    }  
}
```

But when I am debugging the program, i get nothing in both arrays... Constantly show 0x0 when hovering over both. I am sure that most likely it's memory management issue. I'll be much obliged for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never init the arrays, so you are sending the addObject message to nil.

Before trying to add objects into your arrays, call in the init of the class that owns the arrays:

```
lastItemForFormula = [NSMutableArray new];
lastItemForExpression = [NSMutableArray new];
```

And then be sure to release the arrays in your dealloc.

Comment: You forgot to retain 'em. Fixed.

Comment: @bbum quite similar case was happening to lately... what u suggest in that case????

Comment: I'm still learning objective-c myself, but I thought that since the property was defined as (nonatomic, retain), that by assigning the array to the property that it would automatically be retained.  Also, is [NSMutableArray new] preferred to [NSMuteableArray array]?  I thought that "new" would only work in Objective-c++...